# Como hacer re direccionamiento con Django?

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo en Django. He descargado el template "Ela Admin" para adecuarlo a un sistema que planeo hacer para la facultad. Mi primer problema importante fue insertar imagen con Django, utilizando codigos como `{% load static i18n %}` e `<img src="{% static 'ruta' %}" />`. Ahora bien, lo siguiente que debo hacer es el redireccionamiento mediante `<a href>`, el cual, imagino, necesita etiquetas similares a las de la imagen. 
Podrian indicarme como utilizarlo? Adjunto imagenes para guiarlos.

Lo que quiero hacer es, desde **prueba.html**, redireccionar a **index.html**; los cuales se encuentran en la misma ruta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Prueba.html**

```
{% load static i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <title> prueba </title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h2> Prueba </h2>

        <img src="{% static 'img/logo2.png' %}" />

        <p><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>

    </body>

</html>
```

**VIEW**

```
class Index(TemplateView): #Clase principal del index
  template_name = 'index.html'
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('syslab/', include(('syslab.urls', 'syslab'))), #URL principal
    path('', Inicio.as_view(), name = 'prueba'),
    path('index/', Index.as_view(), name = 'index')
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder hacer un direccionamiento usando `<a href>`, debes de indicar en el hipervículo, url + el nombre del path entre porcentajes (`%`)

```
 <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="...">
```

Entre comillas simples, se le indica el `name` de la url.

En el caso de  `path('', Inicio.as_view(), name = 'prueba')` sería

```
 <a href="{% url 'prueba' %}" class="...">
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien. Te lo agradezco. La cuestión ahora es que al redireccionar se pierde buena parte del Bootstrap. No me muestra la página con todos los estilos. Como podria arreglar esto?

Comment: Has probado la herencia de plantillas? https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/es/template_extending/